# Updating Google line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google line chart and I set event to put data in chart. When I use this event for first time it worked fine but, when I use it for second time the new data over write with the previous data but I don't want that. I want to keep the data together not over writing when I think about this problem I realized that I can solve this problem with saving data each time and put them in for loop but I think it's not proper way to do that is there any other way to solve this problem

Here is my JS code :

```
function drawChart() {
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'example1'); // Implicit domain label col.
    data.addColumn('number', 'example2'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    $("#Sample").click(function () {
        var test1 = $("#sample1").val();
        var test2 = $("#sample2").val();
        var test3 = $("#sample3").val();
        data.addRows([
            [test3, test1],
            [test3, test2]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, {
            pointSize: 5
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your main problem stems from the fact that you are registering a click even to add the columns as well as draw the chart. I would seperate the initial drawing of the chart into the page-load and in the click handler you would just find the google-chart and update the series data on the chart.

Comment: you mean I should separate the `add.colunms` and put it out form event?

Comment: I am not sure it will necessarily fix your problem, but seperating out your handler (everything inside the click function) into it's own function to have a bit more clarity into whats breaking down on you.

Am I correct in assuming you're trying to add a point to the linegraph and advance it ?

Comment: yes I want it some how but it's not the problem the problem is over writing data each!!!!and actually I separated but nothing changed!!!

Comment: With a few small adjustments, this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/vbLha3j4/.  Is that what you intended, or is there something else that needs to be fixed still?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you didn't separate `add.columns` part form your event and every time you call event make another columns and your data over write.

Your solution:

```
function drawChart() {
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'example1'); // Implicit domain label col.
data.addColumn('number', 'example2'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
$("#Sample").click(function () {
    var test1 = new Number($("#sample1").val()).valueOf();
    var test2 = new Number($("#sample2").val()).valueOf();
    var test3 = new Number($("#sample3").val()).valueOf();
    data.addRows([
    [test3, test1],
    [test3, test2]
    ]);
    chart.draw(data, {
    pointSize: 5
    });
});
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```